# Simple parsing of strings in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm not sure about the best way to approach this, so I figured I'd ask. I have a line like this :

```
NAME="/dev/sda" TYPE="disk" MODEL="KINGSTON SV300S3"
```

(gotten from lsblk with a few options) and I'd like to extract each field as simply as possible. Yes, I know lsblk has a very nice --json, but that's unfortunately a recent addition I can't use, we have some pretty old servers still in production.

Maybe using Str with some regex ? Google seems to say menhir a lot, I've never used it, but I'm afraid that might be a bit heavy just for a few variables like that ?
I've tried using String.split_on_char and String.slice, but it starts getting complicated when model contains spaces, String.split_on_char doesn't ignore spaces between double quotes of course.

Comment: Menhir is extremely overkill for this. Regular expressions seem like the natural way to go here.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do this ? I find plenty of checks, but I can't find any substring extractions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `Str` could probably do the trick, the lesser-known [`Genlex` module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Genlex.html) from the standard library can come quite handy for not-too-heavy string manipulation, at least for formats that more or less obey OCaml's lexical convention. Basically, it will transform your `char` stream into a stream of tokens that you can parse much more easily. I imagine that the full output format of `lsblk` might require some refinements, but for your example, the following is sufficient:

```
let lexer = Genlex.make_lexer [ "=" ]

let test = "NAME=\"/dev/sda\" TYPE=\"disk\" MODEL=\"KINGSTON SV300S3\""
let test_stream = Stream.of_string test
let test_stream_token = lexer test_stream

let info =
  let l = ref [] in
  try
    while true do
      let kw = Stream.next test_stream_token in
      let eq = Stream.next test_stream_token in
      let v = Stream.next test_stream_token in
      let kw =
        match kw with Ident s -> s | _ -> failwith "Unrecognized pattern"
      in
      let () = match eq with Kwd "=" -> () | _ -> failwith "Expected '='" in
      let v = match v with String s -> s | _ -> failwith "Expected string" in
      l:=(kw,v)::!l
    done;
    assert false
  with Stream.Failure -> List.rev !l
```

Basically, the main loop considers that the information contained in the input is a sequence of items of the form `<key>="<value>"`, decomposed in three tokens by the `Genlex`-generated lexer.

It results in: `[("NAME", "/dev/sda"); ("TYPE", "disk"); ("MODEL", "KINGSTON SV300S3")]`

Comment: I never heard about genlex, but your function here basically does exactly what I need ! It'll work out of the box even if I decide I need new columns some day, that's perfect. Thanks a lot ! Now to try and understand it :)

Answer (score 6):

For simple format like this, the Scanf module might be a viable alternative:

```
let extract s = Scanf.sscanf s "NAME=%S TYPE=%S MODEL=%S" (fun x y z -> x, y ,z);;
;; extract {|NAME="/dev/sda" TYPE="disk" MODEL="KINGSTON SV300S3"|}
```

yields

> ("/dev/sda", "disk", "KINGSTON SV300S3")

as expected.

Comment: Scanf always makes me cringe, but it's clearly the right tool for the job here.

Answer (score 1):

Got it :

```
let re = Str.regexp "NAME=\"\\(.*\\)\" TYPE=\"\\(.*\\)\" MODEL=\"\\(.*\\)\"" in
  match Str.string_match re line 0 with
  | false -> [`Null]
  | true  ->
     let name = Str.matched_group 1 line in
     let typ = Str.matched_group 2 line in
     let model = Str.matched_group 3 line in
     Printf.printf "%s, %s, %s\n" name typ model
```